# How can I retrieve only controls with Name property when iterating through container?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I currently have a StackPanel, that I am dynamically adding controls to. (Presently other stack panels, DatePickers, ComboBoxes, TextBoxes and Labels.)  The intent, is I am trying to dynamically generate search critera options based on the currently selected report type.  In doing this I am setting the name so I can access it later, however, I am running into an issue where I can't seem to get all of the user input controls I want without either missing something or crashing, because StackPanels don't have a Name property.

```
// This one crashes because a child StackPanel doesn't have Name
foreach (var child in this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children)
{
    switch (((Control)child).Name)
    {
        case "startDate":
            this.reports[index].StartDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "endDate":
            this.reports[index].EndDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "employeeId":
            this.reports[index].EmployeeId = (int)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue != 0 ? (int?)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue : null;
            break;
        case "jobNumber":
            this.reports[index].JobNumber = ((TextBox)child).Text;
            break;
    }
}
```

.

```
// This one skips over the DatePickers
foreach (var child in this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children)
{
    switch (((FrameworkElement)child).Name)
    {
        case "startDate":
            this.reports[index].StartDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "endDate":
            this.reports[index].EndDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "employeeId":
            this.reports[index].EmployeeId = (int)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue != 0 ? (int?)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue : null;
            break;
        case "jobNumber":
            this.reports[index].JobNumber = ((TextBox)child).Text;
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm also open to alternative suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Edit #1:
Here is the initialization and adding of the startDate DatePicker:

```
var startDateStackPanel = new StackPanel
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        startDateStackPanel.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Start Date:" });
        startDateStackPanel.Children.Add(new DatePicker { Width = 120, Name = "startDate" });
this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children.Add(startDateStackPanel);
```

Edit #2:
I can do this, but it just feels wrong...

```
var list = new List<Control>(this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children.OfType<DatePicker>());
list.AddRange(this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children.OfType<ComboBox>());
list.AddRange(this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>());

foreach(var child in list)...
```

Comment: You can reflect [use reflection] your object and check if the property name exists

Comment: switch ((string)child.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(child, null))... still skips over the DatePickers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching for descendants from e.g. FrameworkElement you can replace your for-each loop in the first example with

```
foreach (var child in this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but when I get the children OfType<Control>() it doesn't include DatePickers

Comment: Sorry, was thinking in Winforms. Try <FrameworkElement> instead.

Comment: For some reason, <FrameworkElement> doesn't include DatePickers

Comment: Strange. In my test project (consisting of a Button, Label, TextBox and DatePicker) it is included.

Comment: Just checked MSDN: DatePicker is derived from Control which is derived from FrameworkElement. Maybe your DatePicker is the child of another control that you not iterated into.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, I've got the datepicker in a child StackPanel

Answer (score 1):

The (probably less than ideal) way I solved a similar problem was as follows:

```
foreach (var child in (from Control c in this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children
                       where !(c is StackPanel)
                       select c))
{
    switch (child.Name)
    {
        case "startDate":
            this.reports[index].StartDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "endDate":
            this.reports[index].EndDate = ((DatePicker)child).SelectedDate;
            break;
        case "employeeId":
            this.reports[index].EmployeeId = (int)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue != 0 ?(int?)((ComboBox)child).SelectedValue : null;
            break;
        case "jobNumber":
            this.reports[index].JobNumber = ((TextBox)child).Text;
            break;
    }
}
```

In effect, it's skipping over all the children that are not of a type that has a Name property.  You could also do it with an `if(c is Stackpanel) continue;` but Linq is always my goto for iteration, in case I want to modify it later.
I later wrapped the relevant classes to eliminate the (all-to-frequent) switch statements.

Comment: It throws an InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'."

Comment: @TheSelected Move the cast into the select clause: `from Object c in this.SearchCriteriaStackPanel.Children
                       where !(c is StackPanel)
                       select (Control)c`